# How to patch group in aws sso using SCIM

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on

I am new to aws sso, so don't know much about it. I was reading [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/developerguide/patchgroup.html)

When I am trying to add user in a group I am getting 400. I am passing the group-id in URL and user id through body.

```
request_url_user = https://scim.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{tenant_id}/scim/v2/Groups/groupID
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Authorization: Bearer <bearer_token>
 
{
   "schemas":[
      "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
   ],
   "Operations":[
      {
         "op":"add",
         "path":"members",
         "value":[
            {
               "value":userID
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

r = requests.patch(request_url_user, headers=headers,data= body)

I am not sure, why I am getting 400 as I have literally the same syntax and everything.

PS- They have this constraint in doc.

> Only displayName, members, and externalId attributes are allowed in
> the request.

The id I am using to add a member is Group id and user id, not the external id. i have created the sso group manually, so there is no external id there. Any way I can add external id to it or any workaround this ?

Comment: Does the 400 have any information in the body of the response as to the reason of the failure? And are you passing the value of id as an integer or a string? Your example doesn't have quotes on the userID value.

Comment: 'detail': 'Request is unparsable, syntactically 
incorrect, or violates schema.', this is what I am getting, I think it's a validation error. Also, I have updated the question, could you please take a look at it

Comment: You missed the other question - is the value that you are passing for the members.value attribute enclosed in quotes, as a string should be?

Comment: yes it is a string, stored in user variable attribute

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I make a patch request using this ? i have been trying but not able to do it

Comment: I tried using postman and it did work for me